# Cron job creating empty file each time it runs

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script I want to run every minute to see if there are draft news posts that need to be posted. I was using "wget" for the cron command in cPanel, but i noticed (after a couple days) that this was creating a blank file in the main directory every single time it ran. Is there something I need to stop that from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: if you don't get much traction here, try stackoverflow.com for this question.

Comment: what does the crontab in question look like?

Comment: What's the name of the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to send the output of that `wget` command to `/dev/null` if you want to avoid creating a file of the (blank) response from your php script.

Example in `curl`

```
curl -q http://your.server/script.php > /dev/null
```

Example in `wget`

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://your.server/script.php
```

If you have the choice, you should use `curl`, that is a better tool for this job.

Comment: Differences between wget & curl http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your script, or the filename or the crontab entry it's hard to guess, but this is what I'd look at first. Try adding one or both of `-o /dev/null` and/or `-O /dev/null` to the parameters of your `wget` call. The first one sends stderr to the bit bucket and the second one sends the files that wget would download there. You can also use the `-q` switch to turn off other output. Your choice of these depends on how you're using `wget`.

Answer (score 3):

```
wget --delete-after
```

is the key :-)

Comment: Ohh, nice. I didn't know that option, i'm a `curl` man myself.